# How can I avoid #includ-ing <sstream> thanks to a template function?

Tags: c++, dependencies, header-files

I have written a very simple logging class.

The logging class has a function that looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void log (T && first, Args &&... rest) {
  log (std::forward <T>    (first));
  log (std::forward <Args> (rest)...);
}

template <typename T>
void log (T && last) {
  /* use <sstream>'s std::ostringstream to convert each T to its string
     representation, then print it via a callback. */
}
```

Since my logging class is likely to be used often throughout my program, I am trying to reduce the amount of code that's going to be tacked onto each translation unit as the result of `#includ`-ing my logger file.

I have managed to move all the `#include` statements except `<string>` out of the header file and into the implementation file, *except* the entirety of `<sstream>` and all of it's dependencies, which are required for the implementation of this template member function.

I have considered explicitly instantiating all of the overloads I need, but if I hope to use my logger with string literals, then I think I'll have to explicitly instantiate a template for each `n` in `const char (&) [n]`.  Or `#include <type_traits>` for `std::decay`.  :(

Is it possible to avoid having to to drag `<sstream>` into all the TUs that use my logger?  How?

Comment: Have you thought of using `std::to_string()` (C++11)? See if that helps to remove `<sstream>`. For the other classes, you may implement class specific `public` method `to_string()`.

Comment: Perhaps [PIMPL idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) could be relevant

Comment: @iammilind Hmm.  I could do the conversions to string myself (with `to_string()` and so on).  I don't _really_ need `<sstream>` to do that.  For anything else, a "to_string" (non?)-member function would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: If all your `log` function is doing is wrapping a stream, why don't you just implement `operator<<`?

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper No reason not to.  I find the function-call syntax nicer, frankly, and I will largely be using this via macros (for line number, file, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

One way in my project I have incorporate is to use `std::to_string()` from C++11. This can avoid usage of `<sstream>`. You may have to include `<string>` header only. For specific classes, you may implement their own public methods of `to_string()`s.

But Android version (we used till mid-2016) didn't have `std::to_string()` unfortunately even with C++11. In such case, we have to rely on `sstream`. However, you may avoid including `<sstream>` in the header file by using below `template` & macro trick (toy code):

```
// header.h
template<typename ostringstream, typename T>
std::string my_to_string (T&& value)
{
  ostringstream oss;
  oss << value;
  return oss.str();
}

#define my_to_string(X) my_to_string<std::ostringstream>(X)
```

Now, in all the implementations you have to put `<sstream>` and use as below:

```
// implementation.cpp
#include<sstream>
int main ()
{
  double d = 1.2345;
  std::string s = my_to_string(d);
  std::cout << "converted: " << s << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ix7DDO).

Comment: `to_string` is just a wrapper for `sprintf` (explicitly defined as so by the standard), so you might as well use `sprintf` at this point.

Comment: With this solution I will need to `#include <sstream>` everywhere, which defeats the point of not simply including it in the header file.  Interesting trick with the template instantiation.

Comment: @MaxBozzi, yes that is correct. There is something called `<iosfwd>` which will help you to some extent for forward declaring certain `std::`s. But if you want to use objects from `<sstream>` then you must have to `#include` it one or the other way. But if your implementation allows `to_string()` then you can avoid `<sstream>`. @uhoh, I just wanted to keep it more c++, hence used `to_string()`.

Comment: Okay -- I'm unfamiliar with `<iosfwd>`, So let me race to look it up :).  I suppose `to_string` might help when combined with some explicit overloads...

Comment: As the name implies, `iosfwd` only contains forward declarations. By itself, it's not sufficient to use any of the stream libraries.